# choosing a random integer from $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability, infinity, natural-numbers

I heard that if we choose a random positive integer, no matter how big it is, it will be closer to $0$ than $∞$.
I have an interesting question: if we assume that we had an infinite computer which had infinite power and memory, then what would happen if I make it choose a random integer from all $\mathbb{N}$?
The probability of choosing an integer from say $n$ numbers is $\frac{1}{n}$, and since $\lim _{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} =0  $ , that means any number we choose has a probability of $0$ of appearing. So that means any number we choose won’t appear. Then what will appear on the screen of the computer? There is a contradiction here, but I don’t know what it means. Does this mean that we can’t choose a random number from all $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Among other things, it means forget about your infinite computer.

Comment: The premise is that $0$ probability does not mean it can't ever happen, just (loosely speaking) *on average* it never should be expected to. Throw a dart at a dartboard; there are infinitely many points it could land on (if throw uniformly randomly and assured to land on the dartboard), so each has a probability of zero ... but it *has* to land ***somewhere***.

Comment: "I heard that if we choose a random positive integer, no matter how big it is, it will be closer to $~0~$ than $~\infty$ " : This is a meaningless statement because there is no such number as infinity.  Infinity is simply a *symbol* of unbounded growth.

Comment: How do you measure the distance from a given positive integer to infinity ?

Comment: @PrincessEev that is very good example and very intersting to think about but that is also confusing if $0$ doesn't mean impossible then what does the probability of $0$ means and what is the probability  of impossible event

Comment: @user2661923 I read that statement on twitter and I don't know if it treue or not but that is not why I wrote it , the reason I wrote it because it got me thinking if the statement was true (loosely speaking) then if I choose a random number $x$ from all $\mathbb{N}$ it must be bigger than any number we ever define also than means $x>n \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$  which doesn't exist and that is where the idea of this question came from

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does this mean that we can’t choose a random number from all $\mathbb{N}$?

Yes, sort of. More formally, there is no way to choose a random number from $\mathbb{N}$ in such a way that every number has the same probability of being chosen (since that probability can't be $0$ and it also can't be positive). There are [probability distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution) you can define on $\mathbb{N}$ but they aren't and can't be [uniform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_uniform_distribution).

A probability distribution on $\mathbb{N}$ is just a sequence $p_1, p_2, \dots$ of non-negative real numbers satisfying $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} p_i = 1$. Examples are given by the [zeta distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_distribution) for $s > 1$.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer , I got a question why this is different from the dart example that @PrincessEev wrote in the comments of probability of $0$ and still possible
is that because $\mathbb{N}$ is discrete ?

Comment: It is different to the dartboard example in that $\mathbb{N}$ is unbounded (it has no upper bound), while the dartboard certainly is. Discrete/continuity has nothing to do with it. Even for real numbers, the continuous uniform probability density function is nonzero only within a finite interval (and zero everywhere else). You can see this with discrete sets too, with dice rolls for example

Comment: @pie: this is partly just a technical issue with how probability measures are defined. In order to make limiting arguments work out nicely they are defined to be what is called countably additive, which means that on a countable set like $\mathbb{N}$ you are just assigning probabilities to each individual natural number and then adding them up. On uncountable sets like $\mathbb{R}$ or $[0, 1]$ we do something more complicated involving integration.

Answer (score 1):

It means that you cannot apply the uniform distribution to the set of natural numbers, period. A computer that does cannot possibly exist. Therefore you'll a) have to be more specific about what "random" means in this context and b) discard the uniform distribution as a possibility when you do so

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have written a computer program that is able to generate (in finite time) any natural number with equal probability of every number occuring. Now for the computer to be able to display that information, it will first print the first digit, then the next and so on. However there is no upper bound to the length of a natural number. Thereby any attempt to display a number will take an amount of time which has no upper bound. Therefore the time taken is infinite in essence. But our original assumption was that the algorithm be completed in finite time. Therefore we have reached an impasse.